# Capture Scratches on LCD Screens

Tags: iphone, smartphone

I am trying to take pictures with a smartphone camera of scratches which may/may not exist on another powered off smart phone. Is there a way to do this without changing the angle of the camera?

Comment: Why "without changing the angle"?

Comment: I need to capture images of many phones so ideally I have a fixed camera pointed a surface and I just replace the "subject" phones.

Answer (score 1):

Change the angle of the lighting?  To make scratches visible, you want them to be able to cast shadows (or rather have a shadow cast onto them), so the lighting should be quite from the side.  Don't use an on-camera light or flash, obviously.